# Search for a string from a given index in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Am relatively new to shell script. I have a variable with string value. I need to search for a string in that variable from given index onwards. For example

```
val="hi hello hi yes no hi good hi"
```

Now i want to search for string "hi" from index 5 onwards in the variable val. how can i achieve this in shell script?

Comment: you can use `grep`

Comment: What do you mean with "search"? Extract it? Do something specific if you find it? Just signal that you found it? Get the positions of all occurrences after index 5? Is it zero indexed?

Comment: In my above example I would need the position of "hi". And then i would extract it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `${val#?????}` to strip off the first five characters, and a simple `case` to check for a match.

```
case ${val#?????} in *hi*) echo "match";; esac
```

Answer (score 0):

To get if it is a match or not, and if it is a match, get position of the searched string. Then you could extract whatever you want.

```
if [[ $val =~ ^(.{5}.*?)(hi) ]]
then
echo "match found"
prefix_len=`echo -n ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} | wc -m`  
echo "$prefix_len"
else
echo "match not found"
fi
```

More specfically,

```
[[ $val =~ ^.{5}.*hi ]]
#          |^^^ ^^-->string you want to search for
#          |  |  |   
#          |  |  any characters(including zero character)                     
#          |  |
#          |  any 5 characters
#          |
# start of line
```

More about regex in bash: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html

Comment: We generally refrain from linking to the ABS because it has, to put it mildly, variable quality.

Answer (score 0):

```
val="hi hello hi yes no hi good hi"

    if [ `echo "${val}" | awk '{print $6}'` == "hi" ]
    then
        echo "Found"
    else
        echo "Not Found"
    fi
```

or

```
val="hi hello hi yes no hi good hi"

    echo "${val}" | cut -f5 -d' ' | grep -qc hello && echo "Found" || echo "Not Found"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
val=(hi hello hi yes no hi good hi)
for i in $( seq 0 $( expr ${#val[@]} - 1 ) ) ; do [ ${val[${i}]} == "hi" ] && echo "'hi' is at position: ${i}"; done
```

This is a solution using an array to allocate all the strings, the for command was used to compare each position to string "hi"

- val=() => It is one of the ways that you can create an array
- $( seq 0 $( expr ${#val[@]} - 1 ) ) => this command was used to create a sequence to go through the array

  - ${#val[@]} => used to identify the array length;
  - expr ${#val[@]} - 1 => used to calc the array length minus one, since the first position of array it's zero
  - 6 was the result of the last command, so the result of the condition is seq 0 6, or 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
- [ ${val[${i}]} == "hi" ] && echo "'hi' is at position: ${i}" => a conditional command to compare each position with the string "hi"

  - ${val[${i}]} => used to access the value inside a position defined by the index "i"

Answer (score 0):

to search for a pattern in string `$val` from index 5 and on

```
grep pattern <<< ${val:5}
```